# When to move a maple sapling?

Tags: trees, maple, tree-removal

I've got a five-foot-tall maple sapling that's growing too close to the house. I want to dig it up and move it somewhere else. Is this feasible? What's the best time of year to do it if so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best time of year is about now (depending on your climate).

Move it as soon as the leaves have changed color. It will be going dormant for winter, but the ground will still be warm enough so the roots can recover from the shock of being moved, without the extra stress of the water needed by the leaves while they were still green.